# SQL Server / EF : keeping track of person's expected attendances

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

For a school project I'm trying to keep track of students (subclass of person), their attendance (eg. wednesday 27-02-2019), and the days they are expected (eg. every monday and wednesday). There are only 5 possible combinations of expected days.

So far I've created a table `Person` with a discriminator for `Student`, and a table `Attendance` with a bridge table between `Person` and `Attendance`.

I have no idea how to keep track of the days they are expected to show up.
The administrator should be able to get a list of students per day, students per expected day combination (eg. Monday & Wednesday is a possible combination) and attendance per student.

I'm struggling to figure out how to store the expected days, my first guess was creating a list with 2 elements, but since this isn't allowed in SQL, I have no idea what other options I have since creating another table for days feels kind of wrong because I already have a table for attendance.

Comment: I'm afraid what we have here is a bit vague, can you be more specific? Sample data and expected results would be nice, or specific detail on the information you're trying to store. SO has guidelines on posting homework help questions as well ([What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)), so we need to see what you've tried so far before we can begin to help you. You won't learn anything if don't try to answer the question yourself, and any answer you get will be more guidance; as it's you that needs to do your homework at the end of the day. :)

Comment: you could have a StudentExpectedWeekDay Table, with columns StudentId, Sunday, Monday, ... Saturday (boolean columns). (StudentId will be PrimaryKey for this table and foreignKey from Person table).

Comment: Does your 'expected days' variable always repeat week to week?  E.g. are the patterns always "Monday and Wednesday" or could they sometimes be "every other day" or "alternating Monday/Wednesday with Tuesday/Thursday"?

Comment: Assuming the former, I'd go with @Matt.G's suggestion.

Comment: @Larnu, I'm afraid there is nothing I can show since I'm stuck at figuring out how to store the expected days, I tried using a string array in the student class, but as far as I'm aware, storing lists, arrays etc as column in a database isn't allowed.

Comment: @APH Yes, expected days is repeating. If a student has Monday and wednesday, he is expected to show up every Monday and Wednesday, but if the person is sick, he can attend class on Tuesday, but gets registered as unexpected student for that day